# Quick launch link for specific users or on specific page in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: permissions, quick-launch, hide-elements

Okay so I have a page up in production that is only for certain people until it gets approved (I know that's a bad idea but that's how it's currently set up). Is there a way to put the link to it in the Quick Launch bar and have it only appear on a specific page or to certain users (the link not the whole navigation)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same in 2010, but in 2013 I often use Audience Targeting to display quick launch / global navigation to only certain groups of users.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261958%28v=office.14%29.aspx